# pdfkit and pdfkit-table for 1 single PDF

Tags: javascript, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit-table and pdfkit in my nodejs application. I want to use both of these packages together for a single PDF but unable to do so. I am unable to find documentation for it.

```
            // Define the table
            let colums = block.data.content[0];
            let rows = block.data.content.slice(1);

            // Define the table data
            const tableData = [
                [...colums],
                ...rows,
            ];

            // Define table properties
            const tableProps = {
                columnSpacing: 10, // Spacing between columns
                fontSize: 12, // Font size for table content
                headerColor: 'black', // Color of the header row
                fillColor: 'white', // Fill color for non-header rows
                headerAlign: 'center', // Alignment of the header row
                align: 'left', // Alignment of non-header rows
                valign: 'center', // Vertical alignment of all rows
                headerHeight: 20, // Height of the header row
                height: 30 // Height of non-header rows
            };

            // Set the initial position for drawing the table
            let tableTop = 50;
            let tableLeft = 10;

            // Draw the table on the document
            doc.font('Helvetica-Bold').fontSize(12);
            let currentTop = tableTop;

            // Draw the header row
            doc.fillColor(props.headerColor)
                .text(data[0].join('   '), tableLeft, currentTop, { align: props.headerAlign });

            // Draw the remaining rows
            doc.fillColor(props.fillColor);
            for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                currentTop += props.height;
                doc.text(data[i].join('   '), tableLeft, currentTop, { align: props.align, valign: props.valign });
            }

        `
```

This is my attempt

Comment: Sorry but I don’t see where are you using the tableData in your code at all. pdfkit-table in nature is just an extension of the original pdfkit. You could just use the pdfkit-table and would have all the features from pdfkit straight away.